# android:ellipsize in ICS text continues after ellipsis

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, truncate

I have a textview that I am programmatically setting maxLines with and then setting it to android:ellipsize="end".  It works partially, but for some reason the text that is being truncated continues for a few characters after the ellipsis in 4.2.2.  It is the actual text that is being truncated, not new characters.

It also is not working properly in 2.3.6 as it adds an ellipsis for each section with a line break or "\n".

I am not using any custom fonts, I have seen that has caused problems before.

Here is where I calculate and set the maxlines:

```
final TextView reviewView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPosition3);

ViewTreeObserver observer = reviewView.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int maxLines = (int) reviewView.getHeight() / reviewView.getLineHeight();
        reviewView.setMaxLines(maxLines);
        reviewView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
        reviewView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        //reviewView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentTestLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/restaurantImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/test"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        />    

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/squareBlack"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/restaurantImage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/restaurantImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/square_black_small"
        />  

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPosition"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/squareBlack"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/squareBlack"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/squareBlack"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/squareBlack"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a test"
        android:textSize="25sp" 
        android:textColor="#a6cbff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/squareBlue"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/squareBlack"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/squareBlack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/square_blue_small"
        /> 

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPosition1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/squareBlue"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/squareBlue"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/squareBlue"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/squareBlue"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7.5"
        android:textSize="25sp" 
        android:textColor="#902515"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restaurantName"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/restaurantImage"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/restaurantImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Restaurant Name"
        android:textSize="25sp" 
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/greybar"
        />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPosition2"
        android:layout_below="@id/restaurantImage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="February 15, 2013"
        android:textColor="#555"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp" 
        />

      <Button android:id="@+id/readReview"
        android:background="@drawable/readreview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Read the Review" 
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textColorHighlight="#ccc"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPosition3"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewPosition2"
        android:layout_above="@id/readReview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColorLink="#C90404"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this programatically, but I'm not sure it's the best solution as it feels like more of a hack.  It seems to be working though.

```
        ViewTreeObserver observer = reviewView.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int maxLines = (int) reviewView.getHeight() / reviewView.getLineHeight();

            reviewView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);


            if(reviewView.getLineCount() > maxLines)
            {
                int lineEndIndex = reviewView.getLayout().getLineEnd(maxLines - 1);
                String text = reviewView.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex-3) +" ...";
                reviewView.setText(text);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

put this in xml

```
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"             
    android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: This won't work, because I need a multi-line textview that dynamically fills up the space of the screen depending on screensize.  Hence why I'm trying to set maxLines programatically.